# Why does my code output ridiculous numbers with the provided set? I'm trying String.format

Tags: java, string.format

I am using these numbers: 5,4,3.5,10,20,40,80,93.33,-1. It will work with something simple with only 5 numbers like: 5,4,3,2,1. What is going on? I am trying to use String.format to shorten the number if that is the issue. Do you guys notice anything within my code that I could do differently to maybe avoid this. This is the output with the provided set:

```
The minimum is -1.0, the maximum is 2.147483647E9, and the average is 2.38609322E8
-238609317.00
-238609318.00
1908874325.00
-238609312.00
-238609302.00
-238609282.00
-238609242.00
-238609229.00
-238609323.00
```

Desired Output

The Minimum is 3.5, The maximum is 93.33, and the average is 31.978749999999998

Score 5.0 is -26.978749999999998 from the average

Score 4.0 is -27.978749999999998 from the average

Score 3.5 is -28.478749999999998 from the average

Score 10.0 is -21.978749999999998 from the average

Score 20.0 is -11.978749999999998 from the average

Score 40.0 is 8.021250000000002 from the average

Score 80.0 is 48.02125 from the average

Score 93.33 is 61.35125 from the average

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int count = 0;
  int arrayLength;
  double min = 99999;
  double max = 0;
  double average;
  double sum = 0;
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program will display the average as well as each numbers distance from the average");
  // need to put loop here.
  arrayLength = IO.readInt("How many numbers will you be entering?");
  if (arrayLength <= 0 || arrayLength > 100)
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing entered, program will close.");
     System.exit(0);
  }
  double[] array = new double[arrayLength];
  for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
  {
     array[i] = IO.readInt("Enter number: " + (i+1));
     count++;  
  } 
  for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
  {
     sum = (array[i] + sum);
     if (array[i] <= min)
     {
        min = array[i];
     }
     if (array[i] > max)
     {
        max = array[i];
     }
  }
  average = (sum / arrayLength);
  System.out.println("The minimum is " + min + ", the maximum is " + max + ", and the average is " + average);
  double[] array2 = new double[arrayLength];
  for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
  {
     array2[i] = (array[i] - average);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
  {
     System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", array2[i]));
  }
```

}

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm at a loss of understanding since you're posting quite a bit of code but not telling us your fully expected and observed outputs or explaining the code and what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not entirely sure how to ask. I added more code

Comment: Again, what output are you expecting and why? What does the code do? Just a little effort put into explaining your code and your problem can go a long way towards helping us understand it better.

Comment: For more on how to ask questions here, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Understood. This is all very new to me. Here is my desired output:

The Minimum is 3.5, The maximum is 93.33, and the average is 31.978749999999998
Score 5.0 is -26.978749999999998 from the average
Score 4.0 is -27.978749999999998 from the average
Score 3.5 is -28.478749999999998 from the average
Score 10.0 is -21.978749999999998 from the average
Score 20.0 is -11.978749999999998 from the average
Score 40.0 is 8.021250000000002 from the average
Score 80.0 is 48.02125 from the average
Score 93.33 is 61.35125 from the average

Comment: Thanks for that -- please post it as an edit to your question so all can see it, and so it can be edited so it will retain formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what happens when you do IO.readInt and put it into a double, but it isn't liable to be what you want...

Comment: This helped a ton. Thank you.